# Mapping DBpedia types to Wikipedia Categories

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to map DBPedia types to Wikipedia Categories, a simple example would be the following SPARQL query

```
select distinct ?cat where {
?s a dbpedia-owl:LacrossePlayer;  dcterms:subject ?cat . filter(regex(?cat,'players','i') )
}  limit 100
```

[SPARQL Result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fcat%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ALacrossePlayer%3B%20%20dcterms%3Asubject%20%3Fcat%20.%20filter%28regex%28%3Fcat%2C%27players%27%2C%27i%27%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D%20%20limit%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)
But this is highly inefficient as it has to first map the DBpedia types to DBpedia Named Entities(resources) and then extract their corresponding Wikipedia categories.  I am trying to do this mapping for a lot of other DBpedia types.
Is there a direct or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You're trying to get all the categories that are used on instances of a given type, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Improving the filter may help…

As an initial note, you may get some speedup if you remove or improve your filter.  You can, of course, just remove it, but you could also make it more efficienct, since you're not really using any special regular expressions.  Just do

```
filter contains(lcase(str(?cat)),'players')
```

to check whether the URI for *?cat* contains the string *players*. It might even be better (I'm not sure) to grab the English **rdfs:label** of *?cat* and check that, since you wouldn't have to do the case or string conversions.

### … but there are *lots* of results.

> But this is highly inefficient as it has to first map the DBpedia
>   types to DBpedia Named Entities(resources) and then extract their
>   corresponding Wikipedia categories. I am trying to do this mapping for
>   a lot of other DBpedia types. Is there a direct or more efficient way
>   to do this?

I'm not sure exactly what's inefficient in this.  The only way that DBpedia types and categories are associated is that resources have types (via **rdf:type**) and have categories (via **dcterms:subject**).  If you want to find the connections, then you'll need to find the instances of the type and the categories to which they belong.   There **may** be some possibility that you can look into whether any particular infoboxes provide categories to articles and are used in the infobox mapping to provide DBpedia types.  That's the only way to get category/DBpedia-types directly, without going through instances that I can think of, and I don't know whether the current dataset has that kind of information.

In general, since Wikipedia categories are *not* a type hierarchy, there will be *lots* of categories with which instances of any particular type are associated.  For instance, we can count the number of categories associated with the types **Fish** and **LacrossePlayer** with a query like this:

```
select ?type (count(distinct ?category) as ?nCategories) where {
  values ?type { dbpedia-owl:Fish dbpedia-owl:LacrossePlayer }
  ?type ^a/dcterms:subject ?category 
}
group by ?type
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Ftype%20%28count%28distinct%20%3Fcategory%29%20as%20%3FnCategories%29%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Ftype%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3AFish%20dbpedia-owl%3ALacrossePlayer%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Ftype%20%5Ea%2Fdcterms%3Asubject%20%3Fcategory%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup%20by%20%3Ftype%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
type                                        nCategories
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/LacrossePlayer  346
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Fish            2375
```

That query responds pretty quickly, and you can even get those categories pretty easily, too:

```
select distinct ?type ?category where {
  values ?type { dbpedia-owl:Fish dbpedia-owl:LacrossePlayer }
  ?type ^a/dcterms:subject ?category 
}
order by ?type
limit 4000
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Ftype%20%3Fcategory%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Ftype%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3AFish%20dbpedia-owl%3ALacrossePlayer%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Ftype%20%5Ea%2Fdcterms%3Asubject%20%3Fcategory%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20%3Ftype%0D%0Alimit%204000%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

When you start using types that have many more instances, though, these counts get big, and the queries take a while to return. E.g., a very common type like **Place**:

```sql
select ?type (count(distinct ?category) as ?nCategories) where {
  values ?type { dbpedia-owl:Place }
  ?type ^a/dcterms:subject ?category 
}
group by ?type
```

```
type                               nCategories
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place  191172
```

I wouldn't suggest trying to pull all that data down from the remote server.  If you want to extract it, you should load the data locally.

Comment: I thought that is how they label the DBPedia types to Wikipedia instances, by Mapping. I just wanted to see if there is something similar rdf:type or dcterms:subject that would map types and categories directly. Thanks again for the quick response.